# How to name dataframes with a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to read several files json files and write them to a dataframe with a for-loop.

```
review_categories = ["beauty", "pet"]

for i in review_categories:
    filename = "D:\\Library\\reviews_{}.json".format(i)
    output = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=filename, lines=True)
return output
```

The problem is I want each review category to have its own variable, like a dataframe called "beauty_reviews", and another called "pet_reviews", containing the data read from reviews_beauty.json and reviews_pet.json respectively.

Comment: `beauty_reviews, pet_reviews = [pd.read_json(path_or_buf="D:\\Library\\reviews_{}.json".format(i), lines=True) for i in review_categories]`?

Comment: what if the length of the review_categories is `n` ?

Comment: @akashkarothiya I don't think I need to assume something that is not stated in the question. In such a case, then OP may need to edit the question to indicate that that may be a possibility.

Comment: got your point, @Abdou Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Abdou! Can't believe the solution could be so simple. Facepalm moment!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is easy to handle the dataframes in a dictionary.  Try the codes below:

```
review_categories = ["beauty", "pet"]
reviews = {}

for review in review_categories:
     df_name = review + '_reviews' # the name for the dataframe
     filename = "D:\\Library\\reviews_{}.json".format(review)

     reviews[df_name] = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=filename, lines=True)
```

In *reviews*, you will have a key with the respective dataframe to store the data. If you want to retrieve the data, just call:

```
reviews["beauty_reviews"]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can first pack the files into a list

```
reviews = []
review_categories = ["beauty", "pet"]
for i in review_categories:
    filename = "D:\\Library\\reviews_{}.json".format(i)
    reviews.append(pd.read_json(path_or_buf=filename, lines=True))
```

and then unpack your results into the variable names you wanted:

```
beauty_reviews, pet_reviews = reviews
```