# Renaming a dataframe in Python using for loop

Tags: python, list, dataframe, rename

I am trying to address a problem similar to the one done in 
[How to name dataframes with a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977487/how-to-name-dataframes-with-a-for-loop)

```
review_categories = ["beauty", "pet"]
reviews = {}

for review in review_categories:
    df_name = review + '_reviews' # the name for the dataframe
    filename = "D:\\Library\\reviews_{}.json".format(review)

    reviews[df_name] = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=filename, lines=True)
```

In reviews, you will have a key with the respective dataframe to store the data. If you want to retrieve the data, just call:

```
reviews["beauty_reviews"]
```

But what if I want to rename the data frames

```
reviews["beauty_reviews"] & 
reviews["pet_reviews"]
```

to something else what is the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want to rename de variable dataframe name or the column name, but here's the answer for both:

"Rename" the dataframe name

```
new_name = reviews['beauty_reviews']
```

Rename the column:

```
reviews.rename(columns={"beauty_reviews": "new_beauty", "pet_reviews": "new_pet"})
```

Comment: You are suggesting a column renaming while I want  to unpack dataframes reviews['beauty_reviews'] & reviews['pet_reviews'] & give them some other name

Comment: maybe this helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225275/how-to-unpack-the-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-to-multiple-variables)